# Adding files in non-master branches (only) but not in master branch

Tags: git, gitlab

I am using **gitlab** for project hosting and ci for a project.
I have a use case where a developer has to add a file in his/her branch. But while merging that branch to master, one specific file should not be added to the master branch.

I tried the following solution to this:

- I added the filename(testfile) to gitignore of master and pushed the changes.
- Then, I checked out a branch "dev" and added the file "testfile" using:

  git add -f testfile
- the file got added and I committed and pushed the changes.
- But, when I merged the "dev" branch to master, the testfile also got merged(added) in the master branch.

  P.S. Technically, It shouldn't have been the case as I forced added the file only on dev branch and while merging I didn't even get the warning message.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest reading up on what `.gitignore` does.  It has no affect on merges, nor is it intended to.  Your comment

> P.S. Technically, It shouldn't have been the case as I forced added the file only on dev branch and while merging I didn't even get the warning message.

suggests some confusion about how force adding (and staging in general) works.  Once a file has been staged (force or otherwise) and committed, it does not have to be staged again for a merge.  (At a technical level, stage entries *are* created during the merge, but this process is not conditioned on exclusion rules because the content is already committed.  If it helps I suppose you could think of every file seen during a merge being force-added to the merge's staging area.)

More generally, branches are expected to have different versions (reflecting different lines of changes) of *the same* content[1].  The idea that some file is permanently "on" some branch but not another is not aligned with how git works.

As EncryptedWatermelon suggests, you could create some manual process that produces the desired result, but I would expect more often than not those manual steps would be forgotten.  If you really want the devs to hate you, you could create server-side hooks that reject any commit to master containing the file; then when they forget to follow the manual process, sometime later when they try to push master the server will reject the push, and they'll have to go back and fix it.

Or, you can rethink your use case and come up with a sane behavior that meets the actual need while working with git the way git is meant to work.  Since you haven't explained the use case, I can't offer any further details about what that would look like.

---

[1] It is possible to have unrelated branches (or even groups of branches) in a single repo, with content that doesn't need to match up; but that's a totally different use case that amounts to having a single repo contain what would normally be multiple repos.  But if two branches are going to be merged, then the expectation is that they are versions of the same content

Comment: My use case is:

Every dev branch will run a suite of test cases, and those testcases will be different for each dev branch.So the gitlab pipeline will run for each dev branch the result of testcases will be checked . After passing all testcases and then pipelinbe, dev branch will be merged to master with the file containing the testcases.

Comment: @Ashwani - I would be remiss not to start by saying, as I understand what you're trying to do, I don't recommend it.  Automating tests takes effort, and that effort is really only worth it if you're going to preserve and accumulate the tests.  But if you must... I still wouldn't store them as part of the branch's commits.  The build tooling might provide a more sensible way to store this type of thing.  (Or there are ways you could store it in git but  not in the branch commits... but that's assuming some custom tool setup.)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `--no-commit` flag with the merge then revert the file

```
git merge --no-commit dev
git checkout HEAD <FILE>
git add -A
git commit
```

Comment: I need to merge the "merge request" using gitlab-ui.